# How do I calculate the angular position of an object in relationship to another object in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, let's take into account that 0 degrees is the object A pointing forward, and I have object B at 30 degrees in relationship to object's A perspectif, the angular position of object B in relationship of angle A is 30 degrees.

Now, the part that I think I got figured out, is that I want to sort a list of objects arround object A to find out who's angular position is closest to 0.

This code is inside a foreach loop and leastAngle equals to Mathf.Infinity at the begining, so angleBetween is smaller trying that each iteration gets an enemy with a smaller angular position in relationship of the player, what I want is the variable angleBetween (the angle between the curent enemy inside the foreach loop and the player) to be setup properly.

```
 float angleBetween = Vector3.Angle(transform.up, EnemyTarget.transform.position // Here is where things are not working properly,I still don't know how to work with angles. 

if (angleBetween < leastAngle)
{
    Debug.Log(leastAngle);
    leastAngle = angleBetween;
    target = EnemyTarget.transform;
}
else
    target = null;
```

What's the goal of it all? You may be wandering, I want to create a player aim assist system in a topdown 2D game.

I tried the code I showed up above, and another piece of code that I had a gut that it may work and probably is closer to be the right answer.

This is the other piece of code

```
float angleBetween = Vector2.Angle(transform.up, (EnemyTarget.transform.position - transform.position).normalized)
```

Comment: well you kinda need a 3rd point as if i look at you there are 0 degrees, if im facing away its 180 but neither of us moved. so one has to be say in front of you, the other the object.. it it could be up, down, a 3rd object....

Comment: I suddenly, after hours, stumbled with this https://youtube.com/shorts/xlnkTEyAx7Q?si=FFltzaeyrykLJASt I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your first approach is

- It uses `Vector3.Angle` so any difference in the Z axis would alternate the result which is not desired if your application is 2D in XY

  => you want to stick to `Vector2`
- It uses a direction as first but then a position as second parameter

  => what will actually happen is that you compare your up direction to the vector pointing from world origin `0,0,0` towards the target position. You rather want to use a direction vector like in your bottom code snippet

  ```
  EnemyTarget.transform.position - transform.position
  ```
- And finally your `else` case will overwrite

  ```
  target = null;
  ```

  Just because the current iteration is not the best match does not mean there was no match at all!

  => You want to entirely remove that `else` case! You rather simply want to keep the current value for `target`

So it should rather be e.g.

```
private Transform TryGetBestTarget(private List<Transform> targets)
{
    Transform bestTarget = null;
    var bestMatch = Mathf.Infinity;

    foreach(var target in targets)
    {
        var match = Vector2.Angle(transform.up, (target.transform.position - transform.position));
    
        if(match < bestMatch)
        {
            bestTarget = target;
            bestMatch = match;
        }
        // No else needed/desired here!
        // because in that case bestTarget simply REMAINS the current value
    }

    return bestTarget;

    // or also using `Linq`
    //return targets.OrderBy(target => Vector2.Angle(transform.up, (target.transform.position - transform.position))).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

---

However, you could indeed also rather simply use the [`Vector2.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Dot.html) product of your two vectors since the actual angle doesn't really interest you.

**`Dot` is way cheaper to calculate (compare [source code of `Dot`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/67d5d85abbea076e469a1642e04f3ab50a326bea/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2.cs#L199) and [source code of `Angle`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/67d5d85abbea076e469a1642e04f3ab50a326bea/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2.cs#L208) - spoiler: `Angle` itself even uses `Dot`)!!**

```
private Transform TryGetBestTarget(private List<Transform> targets)
{
    Transform bestTarget = null;
    var bestMatch = Mathf.NegativeInfinity;
    foreach(var target in targets)
    {
        var match = Vector2.Dot(transform.up, (target.transform.position - transform.position));
    
        if(match > bestMatch)
        {
            bestTarget = target;
            bestMatch = match;
        }
    }

    return bestTarget;


    // or also using `Linq`
    //return targets.OrderByDescending(target => Vector2.Dot(transform.up, (target.transform.position - transform.position))).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can actually skip the `normalized` and save a bit work as for `Angle` it doesn't matter at all and you just need the biggest `Dot` result

> For normalized vectors Dot returns 1 if they point in exactly the same direction; -1 if they point in completely opposite directions; and a number in between for other cases (e.g. Dot returns zero if vectors are perpendicular).
>
> **For vectors of arbitrary length the Dot return values are similar: they get larger when the angle between vectors decreases.**

Comment: Thankyou so much, I had already figured out a lot of those things, no all of them, however I had to stay up until 1:30 of the morning to get that part working of the code. In my investigation I found something really interesting, https://forum.unity.com/threads/dot-product-to-360-degrees-or-0-1.650713/#:~:text=float%20direction%20%3D%20Mathf.Sign%28Vector3.Cross%28sunForward%2C%20Vector3.down%29.x%29%3B%20float%20angle%20%3D,%28angle%20%3C%200%29%20angle%20%3D%20360f%20%2B%20angle%3B Basically if anyone needs the scale to be instead of -1 - 1 to be in degrees 0 - 360 this can help